# Routing KVO changes

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I don't like that KVO routes all changes to the same observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: method. At the moment I have a large tree of if statements sending these "observations" to different methods.

Is there already a way to specify a different selector for each addObserver: call?

Otherwise, I was thinking of creating a class "Observation", each instance of which would be initialised with a selector and then act as the KVO observer.

Comment: [mike ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html) has a good article on this, worth checking out

Comment: this is possibly exactly what i was looking for (haven't actually tried it yet though). thanks!